# Why does my React Component not rerender after setState?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm fairly new to React & Redux, and I'm struggling with the React rerender mechanic.

I'm trying to write a simple ToDo app. Here is my `ToDoList` class:

```
class ToDoList extends Component<Props, State> {
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            todoList: this.sortTodos(props.todoList)
        };
    }

    render = () => {
        return (
            <List>
                {this.state.todoList.map((todoItem, index) => 
                    <ToDo key={index} info={todoItem} />
                )}
            </List>
        );
    }

    componentWillMount = () => {
        if (this.state.todoList.length === 0)
            this.props.loadToDoList();
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps: Props) => {
        this.setState({ todoList: this.sortTodos(nextProps.todoList) });
    }

    sortTodos = (todos: ToDoModel[]) => {
        return todos.sort((a, b) => a.completed === b.completed ? 0 : a.completed ? 1 : -1)
    }
}
```

When I check a todo, my `ToDoModel` is updated and `componentWillReceiveProps` is called.

I tried to count the number of completed todos and set this number in the state in the `componentWillReceiveProps`. It works, however, for some reason, my todo list isn't rerendered in the updated order, even with a `this.forceUpdate()` at the end of the function. (Actually, my todo isn't checked and re-ordered until I reload the screen.)

What am I missing?

Comment: Which part is using redux? Where is your react connect? Why do you still tie `todoList` in local state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because of the `key` in `Todo` item. Try setting the key to the id of the item

```
<List>
  {this.state.todoList.map((todoItem, index) => 
    <ToDo key={todoItem.id} info={todoItem} />
  )}
</List>
```

Answer (score -1):

Inside map try to return the component:

```
{this.state.todoList.map((todoItem, index) => 
  return <ToDo key={index} info={todoItem} />;
)}
```

Comment: They're using the arrow function implicit return syntax - your code is functionally equivalent to what they already have,